# Android Studio Error "Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context."

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to have the text in a TextView change on a button click with this code:

```
    button_change_text.setOnClickListener(
        textView3.text="Hello World!"
    )
```

I saw it on many tutorial videos and forums but I get the following error when I attempt to build the app:

> Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (Check the interpretation of token `=`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button_change_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     textView3.setText("Hello World!"); 
   }
});
```